# RESTful web service for complex SQL queries

Tags: sql, rest

I am trying to write a RESTful web service which accepts requests and queries a database. The queries, which are variable depending on user input, are not necessarily simple and might need to link multiple tables together. The best way I came up with is to POST the request as XML, specifying the data to be retrieved, the tables involved and the conditions to be satisfied. This way, the corresponding php function will know if and which tables to JOIN and the WHERE restrictions to use for the SELECT statement. Does this sound like a reasonable way of implementing such a request?

Although I have a lot of experience with programming, and some in web technologies, it is the first time that I am implementing a web service. Are there any design patterns for best practices regarding REST services? Any tips and suggestions would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: There are no accepted standards for REST -- it's an architectural style. The web is full of information on this - perhaps you should google it and read about it a little.

Comment: One tip, generally RESTful web services use JSON, not XML, for complex requests and responses.

Comment: JSON sounds simpler than XML actually. Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your desired stack, but in case .NET/mono is an option, you can take a look at WCF REST Services, which allow you to generate a model based on the database and expose customizable OData REST service based on that model with little to no code.

In case it is not an option, i would still look at implementing OData endpoint for your DB as there are existing clients and client libraries for most platforms.

[WCF REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx)

[ODATA queries](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/)

Comment: He mentioned PHP in the question, not sure how helpful this answer is.

Comment: Indeed I will probably using php. However it is still helpful to generally understand the nature of the available tools. Thanks for your help. For such applications, do you guys think that REST is a good way to go?

Comment: @user3612675 There is no simple answer to that. In most of the cases having REST API help a lot.

Comment: Great. Thanks to everyone for all the help